# How to control Movie clips with a timer

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, actionscript-2

i'd be glad if someone could help me with flash and scripting , i want to make an .swf movie which shows a sign and during daytime the sign lights are of and at night the lights are blinking , i already made the movie clips for the blinking sign an the other one i just stuck with the script i just know a very little about AS2.0. and because i wanted to put the sign on a website i thought it must work with the system so the animation works on every system visiting. and i've searched for days, and i couldn't find anything to help me do what i want . please help me i'm desprate. ( and i'm sorry with my English it's not my native language ) Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hi I did an effect using a clip as a sky getting it an alph
However instead of aloha you can use your blinking movie clip to appear gradually according to the hour of day.

Hope this works for you

AS2 Code:

```
miDate = new Date();
var hora:Number = 0; //hora is hour

if (hora>0 && hora<12) {
    sky._alpha = 100-(hora*8);

} else if (hora>=12 && hora<15) {
    sky._alpha = hora;

} else if (hora>=15 && hora<18) {
    sky._alpha = hora*2;

} else if (hora>=18 && hora<21) {
    sky._alpha = hora*3;

} else if (hora>=21 && hora<24) {
    sky._alpha = hora*4;

}
```